# Automatic redirection of FormsAuthentication to other URL than specified in the Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have this section in the Web.config for my MVC3 application:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>
```

Until recently every time the code hit an `[Authorize]` attribute the LogOn.cshtml page was shown. All of a sudden the redirection takes place to Account/Login (not the 'i' instead of the 'O'!!!) and I get a resource not found exception. I did a Find on the Web.config and could not find the word 'login' anywhere! What on Earh can have gone wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the "extra" Web.configs in the View directory sub-tree? Does this happen on both debug and release builds? (different config templates)....  Maybe do a "grep" for Login within your solution.

Comment: There is no reference to Account\Login to be found anywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230) with ASP.NET MVC 3 as stated in the release notes. To solve it simply add the following to the `<appSettings>` node of your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />
<appSettings>
```

or try with the following key as suggested by the release notes:

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
```

Comment: I have to correct that, after a time the problem recurred! I simply renamed the Action to be rid of this annoyance.

Comment: As suggested in the release notes you must use                      <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" /> in conjunction with Darin's second suggestion.Known issues are at times annoying