# Another MVC3 A public action method 'yyyyy' was not found on controller 'xxxxx.Controllers.AccountController'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know it has been asked many many times, but we have just upgraded our server from 2003 to 2012, and suddenly our email is flooded with thousands of email with this error even users does not appear to see these errors (We are using ELMAH to handle error emailing)

The patterns seem to be:

1. it is looking for "A public action method 'Login' was not found on
   controller 'appName.Controllers.AccountController" but there is no
   where in the code is calling 'login' (got heaps of these)
2. We also start getting "'/apple-touch-icon-xxxx.png' was not found"
   error but again we don't code for Apple.

This is our RegisterRoutes code:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );


            //Custom route for Error hander (ELMAH)
            routes.MapRoute(
            "ErrorHandler", // Route name
            "{*path}",      // URL
            new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" }
            );
```

These ALL a bit strange to me, can anyone suggest what should I start looking at?

Thanks in advance.
WM

Comment: Check you `webconfig.cs` file - does it have something like `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />`

Comment: Funny I was just thinking about it...but it has  `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="20" />` instead of `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogIn" timeout="20" />`...so it's true it will get time out after 20 mins, but no idea why it tries to go to 'login' instead of 'logon'...

Comment: Have you set a startup page in Properties -> Web?

Comment: No, it does not appear to be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic redirection of FormsAuthentication to other URL than specified in the Web.Config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220191/automatic-redirection-of-formsauthentication-to-other-url-than-specified-in-the)

Answer (score 0):

Just found it. Apparently a known issue for mvc3 (don't you love Microsoft) [Automatic redirection of FormsAuthentication to other URL than specified in the Web.Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220191/automatic-redirection-of-formsauthentication-to-other-url-than-specified-in-the)